# Why can't I see some of my notes from my iphone on my macbook?

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, notes.app

There are some notes that I created on my iphone and i can't see them on my macbook pro.  I have icloud turned on everywhere and I do see certain notes synced across my devices but some are just on one.

Is there anyway to determine what the issue is?  Is there a known issue with notes not syncing properly?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible you have an email account with "Notes" enabled on your iPhone, but don't have the same account set up on your Mac.

On your iPhone, in the Notes listing, tap "Accounts" in the upper left corner. Mentally review those accounts.

On your Mac, click the Navigation icon that shows two lists next to a box, and makes sure the accounts are the same.

[image: nav button]

If the accounts aren't the same, setup the missing accounts on your Mac in Mail Preferences. Also, if you have an Note "Account" on your iPhone that is named something like "On my iPhone", transfer those notes to an account that syncs. You can accomplish that by, tapping the Share icon in the note, tap "Copy", tap "Notes" to view your list of notes, tap "Accounts", tap an account that will sync to your Mac, tap the "+" icon, tap and hold, paste the note that. (Hopefully you don't have too many notes that need that action).

Comment: thanks that second part worked by copying from "On my iphone". That being said, I don't understand what i am doing wrong.  Are you saying notes created on iphone don't sync?   I would have thought any note created on the iphone would sync to my mac.  If i click "+" when i am looking at "All my notes" view, which account does it create the note under the icloud account (instead of the on my iphone bucket)

Comment: While tedious, it worked to copy, paste into the iCloud notes account from the PC notes account. Thanks, it's been driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add that I found I could simply add a return to the end of each note in iPhone that was not showing up on my Mac and it automatically synced the note the the Mac.  Not sure why it worked but it was easier than copy and pasting every note.

Comment: Apple is really starting to decline in their quality control. If Tim ate his own dog food this would never happen

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem as well, and looked at each of the settings in my iPhone 5 (with OS 9.3.1), after reading the advice above and other threads.

1. In Notes, select the account folder you want to move notes from (ex. On My iPhone)
2. Press "Edit" on the upper right. In the lower left select "Move All", or select each note individually, and then select "Move to..."
3. Your different note account folders will appear, select the iCloud folder if you want your notes to be backed up and synced to all your devices. Or choose another or make a new folder. The notes will copy to that account folder.
4. To confirm the notes are syncing, go to Settings > iCloud > scroll down to Notes and confirm the slider is "on" to sync/backup (green is visible).
5. On your mac or ipad, log into your iCloud account, and check the notes, there may be an minute or two before they all appear. Eventually they will appear in Notes on your mac or other device after they backup/sync to iCloud.

To avoid having notes just on your phone in the "On My iPhone" account:
6. In Settings, scroll down to Notes.
7. Scroll down and turn off "On My iPhone" Account. 
You can start with step 6. first, then a pop-up will notify you of your notes in the "On My iPhone" Account and ask you to move or delete them. Then you follow steps 1. through 5.

Feel free to repost or link to this answer! 8-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a really simple method that just worked first time I tried it randomly by luck.

- Open Notes on iPhone
- go to Notes section (not iCloud notes)
- Click any note > click the Share button > AirDrop to your Mac

.. and your iCloud notes will reappear on Mac. :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with syncing notes. ***The copy paste method worked perfectly***
I opened the iPhone note that I wanted to appear on my macbook, copied the note, went back into the iCloud note folder, opened a new blank note in the iCloud note folder, pasted the data (previously copied from iPhone note) into a new note. It appeared in the cloud note folder on my iPhone as well as the notes folder on my macbook.